# Getters and Setters on angular.extend $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm reading an interesting article [AngularJS: Tricks with angular.extend()](http://moduscreate.com/angularjs-tricks-with-angular-extend/), and there is explained how to use `getters` and `setters` with `extend`. But there are some points that I don't understand.

**Js:**

```
app.controller('ThingController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {

    // private
    var _thingOne = 'one',
        _thingTwo = 'two';

    // models
    angular.extend($scope, {
        get thingOne() {
            console.log("get thing1");
            return _thingOne + 'eeeeee';
        },
        set thingOne(value) {
            console.log("set thing 1");
            if (value !== 'one' && value !== 'two'){
                throw new Error('Invalid value ('+value+') for thingOne');
           }
        },
        get thingTwo() {
            console.log("get thing2");
            return _thingTwo + 'oooooo';
        },
        set thingTwo(value) {
            console.log("set thing 2");
            if (value !== 'two' && value !== 'three'){
                throw new Error('Invalid value ('+value+') for thingTwo');
           }
        }
   });

    // methods
    angular.extend($scope, {
       get things() {
            return _thingOne + ' ' + _thingTwo;
        }
    });

}]);
```

**Html:**

```
<body ng-controller="ThingController">
    {{ things }} // one, two 
</body>
```

My questions:

1. ¿Why on the `get thingOne()` is not returned `oneeeeeee`? (The same for `get thingTwo()`)
2. ¿Where is called the `set thingOne` and the `set thingTwo`? Because I never see on the console `set thing 1` or `set thing 2`.
3. ¿How I can declare a `set method` inside the `angular.extend methods`? ¿It is possible to assing a value from the view?

Comment: If you read the comments on that article, you can see that this doesn't work with getters and setters.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Of course, that's why I'm posting a question here, because I know that this code need some fixes.

Comment: I think that the point of the comments is that it's great in theory but does not work in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
angular.extend($scope, {
    get things() {
        return $scope.thingOne + ' ' + $scope.thingTwo;
    }
});
```

Setter will be called in this case:

```
$scope.thingOne = 'test';
```

Comment: Ok, good. The first one code, works (the getter). But, the setter not, I want to declare (as I said in my question), a `setter method` inside the `methods` . I mean, you have answered only my first question (:

Comment: There is another way in which I can declare a `setter` without `$scope.thingOne`? I mean without using `$scope`.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just do:

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with angular.extend - these are property accessors: getter and setter... allows you to add some logic into read/writing of object fields.

here is how you define one:

```
var instance = {
   get prop() { return this._prop },
   set prop(value) { this._prop = value }
}
```

use it like this:

```
instance.prop = "new value"
var x = instance.prop
```

`angular.extend` only copies this definition to $scope. You can use `Object.define` too.. as seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v1bxyrx1/2/

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I need an answer according exactly to my code.

Comment: strangely enough getters are not fired after a setter is called, not even with brute force $apply() - looks like angular somehow copies $scope fields on its own - still figuring out

Comment: Meanwhile: I see your code on the jsfiddle. It is possible to declare a setter there? (This is only a doubt. It has nothing to do with my original question). Please can you update your fiddle with this (:

Comment: As I tried, a setter can only be declared in this way: `$scope.prop1 = 'new value';` It is possible to do it inside  `Object.assign($scope ... ` like the `getter`?